# overlapping chunks in rsync algorithm

Tags: algorithm, rsync, checksum

I was going through [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) utility and in the section: **Determining which parts of a file have changed** it says: The sender computes the rolling checksum for every chunk of size S in its own version of the file, even **overlapping chunks**.

**Here comes the doubts:**

- Why recipient calculates checksum for non-overlapping block but sender calculates overlapping block of size S?
- And is the size S is same for recipient and sender?
- What is overlapping block? Is it, suppose you have text as: `abcdefgh` and `s=4` than receiver will calculate checksum for `abcd` and `efgh` and send those to sender. And than sender will calculate checksum for: `abcd`, `bcde`, `cdef`, `defg`, `efgh` (is this overlapping chunk) and compare with the receiver.
- Then how it calculates the diff i.e. part which is different in sender and receiver?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the recipient calculated rolling checksums for all the overlapping chunks, there would be almost as many checksums as the size of the file. So sending the checksums to the sender would be more expensive than sending the entire contents of the file, and there would be no savings. So the recipient splits the file into large, non-overlapping chunks, so it can send a small number of checksums and hashes.

The size S has to be the same on the sender and recipient. Otherwise, the checksums and hashes could never be expected to match.

A more detailed explanation of the algorithm can be found [here](http://rsync.samba.org/tech_report/). It makes it clear that S is the same on the sender and recipient.

Here's an example. Suppose the file on the recipient is:

```
abcdefghijkl
```

and S = 4. The recipient will send checksums and hashes for `abcd`, `efgh`, `ijkl` to the sender.

Suppose one character X is inserted into the file on the sender:

```
abcdeXfghijkl
```

It will calculate checksums for:

```
abcd
bcde
cdeX
deXf
eXfg
Xfgh
fghi
ghij
hijk
ijkl
```

It will compare these to the checksums received from the recipient, and determine that `abcd` and `ijkl` have not changed. All it needs to send is `eXfgh`, with instructions that this should replace the `efgh` chunk.